# How do I update Apache Atlas metadata?

Tags: hadoop, apache-atlas

I have a Hortonworks Sandbox.
I have run an Atlas application. There are already all databases, tables and columns from Hive. I have added a new table to Hive, but it didn't appear in Atlas automaticaly.
How do I update Atlas metadata? Is there any good tutorial for Atlas showing how to start e.g. How to import data from existing cluster?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 1):

All metadata are reported to Atlas automatically. Hive should be running with atlas `hook` that is responsible for such reporting.

If you have hive installed as a part of hortonworks platform it should be there, otherwise there is a clear instruction in Apache Atlas documentation of how to install `Hive Hook` (this is kind of extra binary to be added to hive distribution).

In general Apache Atlas documentation is well maintained and cover most of cases.

Comment: I'm using HDP 2.6 Sandbox. Out of the box new tables created in Hive don't appear in Atlas. Where can I check if these hooks are up and running?

Comment: it's installation manual, but all you want to do is to check if relevant services up and running: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_data-governance/content/ch_hdp_data_governance_install_atlas_ambari.html

Comment: how do you create tables in HIVE, if it's via Apache Spark - it won't work. There are no Apache Spark - Atlas integration. Try Ambari HIVE UI.

Comment: I'm using Ambari View Hive 2.0

Comment: I have installed Atlas using Ambari Server and tried creating tables from Ambari Hive View 1.0, Ambari Hive View 2.0, Hive CLI, but tables are not getting reflected in the Atlas. I have gone through most of the documents available with no success. Can any help me out.